# Duplicate INSERT to another PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql

I have checked similar threats but not match exactly that I am trying to do.

I have two identical tables:

- `t_data`: we will have the data of the last two months. There will be a job for delete data older than two months.
- `t_data_historical`: we will have all data.

I want to do: If an INSERT is done into `t_data`, I want to "clone" the same query to `t_data_historical`.

I have seen that can be done with triggers but there is something that I don't understand: in the trigger definition I need to know the columns and values and I don't want to care about the INSERT query (I trust of the client that to do the query), I only clone it.

Comment: trigger functions are exactly for that scenario - why not make use of them?

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. Yes, I guess that the solution are the triggers but I thought that I had to know the columns/values for insert. After read the Laurenz's answer seem that It is now needed (sorry but I am very new in postgresql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the history table will have the same definition, and the name is always constructed that way, you can

```
EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I VALUES (($1).*)',
               TG_TABLE_SCHEMA,
               TG_TABLE_NAME || '_historical')
USING NEW;
```

in your trigger function.

That will work for all tables, and you don't need to know the actual columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will deploy and let you know the results.

Comment: Hi, I got the error: `InternalError: control reached end of trigger procedure without RETURN`. I have changed the USING command by RETURN and then I got an other error.

Comment: I created the trigger like:
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy2historical() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I VALUES (($1).*)', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME || '_historical')
USING NEW;

END;
RETURN NULL;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
  

CREATE TRIGGER copy2historical_tg
AFTER INSERT
ON t_data
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE copy2historical();
`

Comment: It should be `RETURN NEW;`, and it must come before the `END;`.

Answer (score 0):

Laurenz,
I created the trigger like:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION copy2historical() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN

EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO %I.%I VALUES (($1).*)', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME || '_historical')
USING NEW;

END;
RETURN NULL;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;


CREATE TRIGGER copy2historical_tg
AFTER INSERT
ON t_data
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE copy2historical();
```

thanks for your help.